AES-GCM-256 partial decryption
How to decrypt only first block without authentication? I tried with cipher.AEAD, but the Open function expects that at the end there will be tag bytes for authentication. I think I need to create ctr block somehow and then decrypt.
I have tried this
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Key and IV (Initialization Vector) must match what was used to encrypt
    key := []byte("examplekey123456")  // 16 bytes for AES-128
    iv := []byte("1234567890abcdef")  // 16 bytes for AES block size

    // Example ciphertext (first block to decrypt)
    ciphertext := []byte{0x76, 0xa3, 0x4c, 0x2e, 0x87, 0x89, 0xb7, 0xa6, 0xb0, 0xcf, 0x6d, 0x98, 0x55, 0x8f, 0xee, 0x0a}

    // Create AES cipher
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create CTR stream
    stream := cipher.NewCTR(block, iv)

    // Decrypt only the first block
    plaintext := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
    stream.XORKeyStream(plaintext, ciphertext)

    fmt.Printf("Decrypted first block: %x\n", plaintext)
}


For a 16 bytes nonce, the start value of the counter is determined using the GHASH algorithm. Only for a 12 bytes nonce the starting value of the counter is determined by concatenating the nonce with 0x00000001 (by the way, the first value is used for the tag, only the following ones for the encryption). You therefore need a library that enables decryption without authentication or one that exposes the GHASH algorithm.

Do you know library I need to use?

Unfortunately no. Also, library recommendations on SO are off topic. In the end, you need the function deriveCounter(). You can adapt the implementation so that this function is exposed. deriveCounter() requires the nonce as input and returns the initial counter. This must be incremented by 1 and you get the counter that you need for decryption with the CTR mode.

GCM is authenticated encryption. During encryption, an authentication tag is generated which is used to authenticate the data during decryption. The tag is generated by applying the GHASH algorithm to the ciphertext and the additional authenticated data. The encryption itself is performed in CTR mode.
At the beginning, an initial 16 bytes counter is derived. In the case of a 12 byte nonce, the initial counter is created by appending the value 0x00000001 to the nonce. For any other nonce size, the initial 16 bytes counter is derived from the nonce using the GHASH algorithm. The initial counter itself is reserved for determining the authentication tag, the subsequent counter is used as IV for encryption/decryption with the CTR mode.

In your example, the nonce is 16 bytes in size, i.e. the initial counter must be derived from the nonce using the GHASH algorithm. Most implementations do not expose the GHASH algorithm.
Instead of creating your own implementation, it is easier to adapt a ready-made solution to your own requirements, e.g. this one here.
The customized implementation below does the following:

Determine the initial counter from the nonce using the GHASH algorithm (with GhashDeriveCounter()).
Determine the tag using the GHASH algorithm (with GetAuthenticationTag()). This step is optional for your task.
Incrementing the initial counter for decryption.
Decryption in CTR mode with the incremented counter as IV.

package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/subtle"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    // Derive counter
    key := []byte("examplekey123456")
    nonce := []byte("1234567890abcdef")
    aesCipher, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
    aesgcm, _ := GhashInit(aesCipher)
    counter := aesgcm.GhashDeriveCounter(nonce)
    fmt.Println("Initial counter (reserved for tag), hex: " + hex.EncodeToString(counter[:])) // reserved for tag

    // Derive tag (optional)
    ciphertext, _ := hex.DecodeString("710869a3f0dd6e579e9797f7a4f3cb79dc757d0a8a5ba3190d778f44db5ff7b28e665593b61ad1b14fff65")
    aad := []byte("some additional authenticated data")
    tag := aesgcm.GetAuthenticationTag(ciphertext, aad, counter[:])
    fmt.Println("Tag, hex: " + hex.EncodeToString(tag))

    // Increment tag für decryption
    counterInc(&counter)
    fmt.Println("Incremented counter (applied for encryption), hex: " + hex.EncodeToString(counter[:])) // applied for encryption

    // Decrypt with ctr
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
    plaintext := make([]byte, len(ciphertext))
    stream := cipher.NewCTR(block, counter[:])
    stream.XORKeyStream(plaintext, ciphertext)
    fmt.Println("Decrypted data using CTR: " + string(plaintext))
}

const (
    gcmBlockSize         = 16
    gcmStandardNonceSize = 12
    gcmTagSize           = 16
)

func GhashInit(cipher Block) (*gcm, error) {
    var key [gcmBlockSize]byte
    cipher.Encrypt(key[:], key[:])
    g := &gcm{cipher: cipher}
    x := gcmFieldElement{
        BeUint64(key[:8]),
        BeUint64(key[8:]),
    }
    g.productTable[reverseBits(1)] = x
    for i := 2; i < 16; i += 2 {
        g.productTable[reverseBits(i)] = gcmDouble(&g.productTable[reverseBits(i/2)])
        g.productTable[reverseBits(i+1)] = gcmAdd(&g.productTable[reverseBits(i)], &x)
    }
    return g, nil
}

func (g *gcm) GhashDeriveCounter(nonce []byte) [16]byte {
    var counter [gcmBlockSize]byte
    if len(nonce) == gcmStandardNonceSize {
        copy(counter[:], nonce)
        counter[gcmBlockSize-1] = 1
    } else {
        var y gcmFieldElement
        g.update(&y, nonce)
        y.high ^= uint64(len(nonce)) * 8
        g.mul(&y)
        BePutUint64(counter[:8], y.low)
        BePutUint64(counter[8:], y.high)
    }
    return counter
}

func (g *gcm) GetAuthenticationTag(ciphertext, additionalData []byte, counter []byte) []byte {
    tagMask := make([]byte, gcmBlockSize)
    g.cipher.Encrypt(tagMask, counter)
    var y gcmFieldElement
    g.update(&y, additionalData)
    g.update(&y, ciphertext)
    y.low ^= uint64(len(additionalData)) * 8
    y.high ^= uint64(len(ciphertext)) * 8
    g.mul(&y)
    tag := make([]byte, gcmBlockSize)
    BePutUint64(tag, y.low)
    BePutUint64(tag[8:], y.high)
    subtle.XORBytes(tag, tag, tagMask)
    return tag
}

func counterInc(counterBlock *[gcmBlockSize]byte) {
    ctr := counterBlock[len(counterBlock)-4:]
    BePutUint32(ctr, BeUint32(ctr)+1)
}

type Block interface {
    Encrypt(dst, src []byte)
}

type gcmFieldElement struct {
    low, high uint64
}

type gcm struct {
    cipher       Block
    productTable [16]gcmFieldElement
}

func reverseBits(i int) int {
    i = ((i << 2) & 0xc) | ((i >> 2) & 0x3)
    i = ((i << 1) & 0xa) | ((i >> 1) & 0x5)
    return i
}

var gcmReductionTable = []uint16{
    0x0000, 0x1c20, 0x3840, 0x2460, 0x7080, 0x6ca0, 0x48c0, 0x54e0,
    0xe100, 0xfd20, 0xd940, 0xc560, 0x9180, 0x8da0, 0xa9c0, 0xb5e0,
}

func gcmAdd(x, y *gcmFieldElement) gcmFieldElement {
    return gcmFieldElement{x.low ^ y.low, x.high ^ y.high}
}

func gcmDouble(x *gcmFieldElement) (double gcmFieldElement) {
    msbSet := x.high&1 == 1
    double.high = x.high >> 1
    double.high |= x.low << 63
    double.low = x.low >> 1
    if msbSet {
        double.low ^= 0xe100000000000000
    }
    return
}

func (g *gcm) mul(y *gcmFieldElement) {
    var z gcmFieldElement
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        word := y.high
        if i == 1 {
            word = y.low
        }
        for j := 0; j < 64; j += 4 {
            msw := z.high & 0xf
            z.high >>= 4
            z.high |= z.low << 60
            z.low >>= 4
            z.low ^= uint64(gcmReductionTable[msw]) << 48
            t := &g.productTable[word&0xf]
            z.low ^= t.low
            z.high ^= t.high
            word >>= 4
        }
    }
    *y = z
}

func (g *gcm) update(y *gcmFieldElement, data []byte) {
    fullBlocks := (len(data) >> 4) << 4
    g.updateBlocks(y, data[:fullBlocks])
    if len(data) != fullBlocks {
        var partialBlock [gcmBlockSize]byte
        copy(partialBlock[:], data[fullBlocks:])
        g.updateBlocks(y, partialBlock[:])
    }
}

func (g *gcm) updateBlocks(y *gcmFieldElement, blocks []byte) {
    for len(blocks) > 0 {
        y.low ^= BeUint64(blocks)
        y.high ^= BeUint64(blocks[8:])
        g.mul(y)
        blocks = blocks[gcmBlockSize:]
    }
}

func BeUint32(b []byte) uint32 {
    _ = b[3]
    return uint32(b[3]) | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[1])<<16 | uint32(b[0])<<24
}

func BePutUint32(b []byte, v uint32) {
    _ = b[3]
    b[0] = byte(v >> 24)
    b[1] = byte(v >> 16)
    b[2] = byte(v >> 8)
    b[3] = byte(v)
}

func BeUint64(b []byte) uint64 {
    _ = b[7]
    return uint64(b[7]) | uint64(b[6])<<8 | uint64(b[5])<<16 | uint64(b[4])<<24 |
        uint64(b[3])<<32 | uint64(b[2])<<40 | uint64(b[1])<<48 | uint64(b[0])<<56
}

func BePutUint64(b []byte, v uint64) {
    _ = b[7]
    b[0] = byte(v >> 56)
    b[1] = byte(v >> 48)
    b[2] = byte(v >> 40)
    b[3] = byte(v >> 32)
    b[4] = byte(v >> 24)
    b[5] = byte(v >> 16)
    b[6] = byte(v >> 8)
    b[7] = byte(v)
}

Applied test data, s. CyberChef:
key:                examplekey123456
nonce:              1234567890abcdef
AAD:                some additional authenticated data
plaintext:          The quick brown fox jups over the lazy dog
ciphertext, hex:    710869a3f0dd6e579e9797f7a4f3cb79dc757d0a8a5ba3190d778f44db5ff7b28e665593b61ad1b14fff65
tag, hex:           fb086720d6762209023d6eccfda551ae

The test shows that the Go code authenticates correctly (i.e. generates the correct authentication tag) and decrypts correctly.
For the sake of completeness: For your ciphertext, the hex encoded plaintext is 53c340ad0621b0924578981d9e0b4b53.
